# How to run a project with 2 MongoDB databases?

Tags: mongodb, cmd

I am trying to run a project with 2 MongoDB databases(`db1, db2`) those are inside a file named `dump`. I tried the following commands in 2 different terminals inside `dump` folder:

```
mongod --dbpath=db1 --port=27017
mongod --dbpath=db2 --port=27018
```

Or the below command in one terminal outside of the `dump` folder:

```
mongod --dbpath=dump
```

It seems both the ways work with no errors but when I check the project in localhost, it seems databases don't work properly!

How should i run a project with two databases on localhost using Windows10 command line?

There is also a file named `config.js` in the project with the following code:

```
module.exports = {
    'db1URL': 'mongodb://localhost:27017/db1',
    'secretKey' : '1111-2222-3333-4444',
    'db2URL': 'mongodb://localhost:27017/db2'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've gotten hold of a backup made with [mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#mongodump).  That is not in a format ready to be used by the mongod process.

To restore the backup, you would first create an empty directory, then start mongod with dbpath pointing at that directory `mongod --dbpath /datadirectory`, then run use [mongorestore](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#mongorestore) pointing to the dump directory like `mongorestore  dump/`.

Note that since you have attempted to start mongod pointed at dump, it has likely created some new files in these directories which may prevent mongorestore from completing.   If that is the case, you will need to either remove these newly created files (hopefully you can identify them by creation date), or get a new copy of the dump.

Comment: I didn't understand what exactly should I do after running `mongod --dbpath /datadirectory`? Should I open a new terminal and run `mongorestore dump`?

Comment: yes, without other options, the mongod will hold on to the console session, so you will need a new console to run the restore